# HTTP 500 error while trying to loop through a json array

Tags: java, json

I have a java RESTFUL webservice which gets a json array from my angular front end with HTTP POST. The json array is created dynamically inside a form with when you click a button to add more rows to the form, the weird thing is that if I submit with 1 row it works fine and adds the info to my database, but when I try with 2 rows or more I get the 500 error. Maybe my FOR loop to iterate on the json array is not the way it should be?

HTTP POST

```
postNeuromotora(params){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type','application/json');
    return this.http.post(`${this.api}neuromotora/`,params,{
      headers: headers
  }).map(
    (res:Response) => {return res.json();}
  );

  }
```

The json output that is send via http is this

```
 "[ { "pacienteid": 4, "nervonome": "Mediano", "ladonervo": "Direito",                     "latencia": "2", "amplitudedistal": "1", "amplitudeprox": "321", "velocidade": "321", "ondaf": "4" }, { "pacienteid": 4, "nervonome": "Ulnar", "ladonervo": "Esquerdo", "latencia": "3", "amplitudedistal": "2", "amplitudeprox": "321",    "velocidade": "312", "ondaf": "66" }]"
```

Neuromotora java file >

```
public class Neuromotora {
 private int neuromotoraid;
 private String latencia;
 private String amplitudedistal;
 private String amplitudeprox;
 private String nervonome;
 private String ladonervo;  
 private String velocidade;
 private String ondaf;
private int pacienteid;
}
```

Insert method inside neuromotoraDAO

```
public void insert(List<Neuromotora> list) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
            Long id = null;           
            for(Neuromotora n: list ){

                String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO neuromotora(nervonome,latencia,amplitudedistal,amplitudeprox,velocidade,ondaf,pacienteid,ladonervo)"
                + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement stmt = this.con.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
                stmt.setString(1,n.getNervonome());
                stmt.setString(2,n.getLatencia());
                stmt.setString(3,n.getAmplitudedistal());
                stmt.setString(4,n.getAmplitudeprox());
                stmt.setString(5,n.getVelocidade());
                stmt.setString(6,n.getOndaf());
                stmt.setInt(7,n.getPacienteid());
                stmt.setString(8,n.getLadonervo());
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();              

                this.con.commit();       

            }                  

                }
```

And the POST method at my java controller

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("/neuromotora/")
    public Response createNeuromotora(List<Neuromotora> n) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        neuromotoraDAO dao = new neuromotoraDAO();

        dao.insert(n);

        return Response
            .status(200)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
            .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
            .entity(n)
            .build();

    }
```

Stactrace of the tomcat log

```
03-Nov-2017 08:51:04.620 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-348] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [io.github.dggodoi.aprendendo.java.backend.MyApplication] in context with path [/aprendendo-java-backend] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.] with root cause
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:117)
    at io.github.dggodoi.aprendendo.java.data.neuromotoraDAO.insert(neuromotoraDAO.java:45)
    at io.github.dggodoi.aprendendo.java.backend.controllers.ChamadoController.createNeuromotora(ChamadoController.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:198)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. Look into the logfiles and you will find out where the problem is

Comment: 03-Nov-2017 08:27:29.839 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-326] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [io.github.dggodoi.aprendendo.java.backend.MyApplication] in context with path [/aprendendo-java-backend] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.] with root cause
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query. Gonna look for this error

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace to yor question using the edit function.

Answer (score 0):

Seems i had to use executeUpdate instead of query and also the con.commit() cant be inside the for loop, it was closing after executing the query. Now it works! thanks